# The --reject feature in wget doesn't seem to work

Tags: linux, wget, mirroring

I am trying to mirror **most** of a ftp sever using wget.

This particular sever keeps old copies of the data files in a folder called 'backup' inside every subfolder.   e.g.  '/MaffiaOffShore/backup'   '/VeryVeryDodgy/backup', which I don't want  but my attempts at using --reject '*backup*' and using --exclude-directories  '*backup*' and various other combinations, all have the same result, the whole sever is mirrored,  including the backup folder.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exclude directories option is:

```
--exclude-directories=List
```

*not* --exclude-directory as you have included in your question

from the wget **man** page

```
-X list
--exclude-directories=list
   Specify a comma-separated list of directories you wish to exclude
   from download (@pxref{Directory-Based Limits} for more details.)
   Elements of list may contain wildcards.
```

Comment: typo,  but the correct version doesn't work either :-(

Comment: I've just updated my answer '*/backup', which was initially not 100% correct

Comment: That works now, thanks. Not the most 'user-friendly' way of writing the software...

Comment: Be aware that the folders need to be absolute paths! So to block host.org/img/thumbs/ you have to write `--exclude-directories=/img/thumbs/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude `/MaffiaOffShore/backup` from `/MaffiaOffShore/`, try

```
-x/MaffiaOffShore/backup
```

or,

```
--exclude-directories=/MaffiaOffShore/backup
```

explicitly.

---

So, from the base directory you exclude all un-required directories as,

```
-x/MaffiaOffShore/backup,/VeryVeryDodgy/backup
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your attempts fail also on my wget. However, I've just verified that the following works nicely for all nested subdirectories:

```
wget -r ftp://user@xxx --exclude-directories '/backup,*/backup,*/*/backup,*/*/*/backup'
```

The wildcarded '*/backup' will not match /backup but it will match paths like /something/backup. The wildcarded '*/*/backup' will match '/something/else/backup', etc.

Comment: Just tried that, didn't work. One combination I tried gave me a backtrace and crashed!  I'm using version 'GNU Wget 1.11.4', what were you using?  Are you sure that backup folders existed on the sever you tested this on?

Comment: Mine is wget 1.10.2 so it's older. I've created a test directory tree with backup folders all over it. I guess the problem might be that your tree contains a very large number of directories, so the */*/* expands to a big list in the memory?